# Compare and contrast the  HTTP to HTML journey in ASP.NET Web Forms & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, compare, lifecycle, contrast

I am trying to make sense of the complete cycle from the point when a user issues a request from the browser to the point response is rendered for both ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC.

**UPDATE:**

Specifically, the concept of ***Page LifeCycle*** does **not** exist in ASP.NET MVC.

If the answer compares both these technologies from that view point it would be great.

Comment: Have you tried looking it up?  This is all rather well documented, try buying a book.

Comment: @CrazyDart I want this Q to show up when someone else eventually looks this up. Everything is well documented in life, even smart-alec comments like yours. The thing is to articulate it in a simple manner. Just watch out for the answers by the gurus here...and then you'll know

Answer (score 1):

That's an awful lot to ask for a simple question on a Q & A Forum site.  It is pretty close to the definition of "not a real question" per the guidelines of the site:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
>   be reasonably answered in its current form

It ***is*** a real question in most senses, and a good one, but it is overly broad for a simple answer.

However, in the spirit of trying to be helpful, here are a few links that might be helpful:

[How ASP.NET works](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp)

[ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

[How ASP.NET MVC Works](http://howmvcworks.net/GettingStarted/)

[How web servers work](http://www.howstuffworks.com/web-server.htm)

Personally, I like the explanation that came out in the older books from when ASP.NET and .NET in general were "the new thing".  Every one of them did a good job of explaining the difference between static HTML and "dynamic" technologies like [CGI](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/cgi.htm), classic ASP, JSP, and then went into how ASP.NET works.    [Beginning ASP.NET 1.0 with C#](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-ASP-NET-1-0-with-C-.productCd-0764543709,descCd-tableOfContents.html) from Wrox was the first book I read on the subject.

Comment: @David Thanks! See my update... hope that makes this a manageable chunk as opposed  an awful lot :)